# Concurrency vs Rate Limit

Tags: concurrency, rate-limiting

We are planning to implement a rate limiter for our rest based framework. But I am slightly confused which one to implement and which one is more important between concurrency and rate limit.
I found that at majority of places e.g. apache camel people have implemented rate limiting instead of concurrency . 
But to me it appears that rate limting actually makes little to no sense, instead concurrency is what we would always need for service facing multiple concurrent requests?
Please let me know your thoughts about the same.

Comment: Do you mean concurrency and rate limiting for a single client?

Comment: I mean concurrency and rate limting for a service that is going to serve external requests

Comment: So, do you want to limit request rate for requests to your service done by one client or in the whole? Should requests from one client affect requests from another?

Comment: Yes I am talking about limiting requests as a whole rather than per client !

Comment: Then I think you're just talking about a single rate limit across all clients.  The essential difference imo between a rate limit and concurrency is that w/ concurrency it matters how long the requests take.  Rate limits you are just subtracting from how many are left. Concurrency, you subtract, but then you return the token to the bucket when the request finishes.   That may make more sense ideally, but is significantly more complex to implement correctly.  Given pricing at https://www.ratelim.it/pricing I'd say 200x more work.

Answer (score 11):

Rate limiting is probably most useful if you are selling an API and want to maintain a certain price model.

For resilience use cases (e.g. protect API from overload) I'd say that concurrency limiting makes more sense, because it is more flexible for changes in your system and provides a simple way to implement back-pressure.

To illustrate, here's an example:

Server S1 can handle a rate of 10 EPS (events per second). You decide to rate limit calls to it to 8 EPS, just to be safe. Now S1 starts having some issue (e.g. a developer makes the code less performant, disk issues, etc) and can only handle 5 EPS. With the same rate limit you will keep hammering S1 and it will eventually die.

Instead you can calculate the equivalent concurrency limit using [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law). If your average latency is 0.5s, 8 EPS corresponds to a max concurrency of 4, that you are gong to enforce (i.e. drop connections if there are more than 4). Now if S1 starts getting slower (as before), the latency will increase to say 1s. With a concurrency of limit of 4 and a latency of 1s, your rate is now only 4 EPS. So you adapted to the slowness without killing S1!

For more details, here's a talk titled "[Stop Rate Limiting! Capacity Management Done Right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m64SWl9bfvk)" by Jon Moore that goes into more detail. Also you might find the Netflix blog post [Performance Under Load](https://medium.com/@NetflixTechBlog/performance-under-load-3e6fa9a60581)
 about adaptive concurrency limits interesting (great implementation summary [on GitHub](https://github.com/Netflix/concurrency-limits#background)).